# Flutter - FirebaseException ([firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have been building an app for IOS and Android using flutter which uses firebase storage to upload files to cloud storage.I have multiple page from which i can upload files(eg:Theres a page to upload images,a seperate page tp upload pdf) but on certain pages, it throws this Exception:

Note: Page here refers to different Activity like in Android

`FirebaseException ([firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.)`

I use same code to upload files on every page,but it throws this Exception.

When i click the upload button multiple times it will upload Sometime and most of times it fails with this Exception.
I have tried many solution including changing the security rules and adding `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com` as principle.

Iam using IOS Simulator for testing on IOS and physical device for android.Incase pf physical device for adroid i havnt faced any issue yet,but for simulator it throws this Exception

Here's the code i use to upload files:

```
uploadrepfile() async {
print("uploadiong");
final path = '${widget.uid}/Records/';

final file = File(pickedfile!.path!);

final pdfref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);

setState(() {
  uploadTask = pdfref.putFile(file);
});

//final snapshot = await uploadTask!.whenComplete(() {});
final snapshot = await uploadTask!.whenComplete(() {});

final url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
print(url);

FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("Medicalrecords")
    .add({"url": url, "time": DateTime.now()});

setState(() {
  uploadTask = null;
});
```

}

Here's my security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}
match /users/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
}
}
```

Any help is Appreciated

Comment: Can you replace the `putFile()` method with `putData()` and try?

Comment: Any success????

Comment: TBH...I have not tested in iOS simulator after that,In Android i face same problem when deleting files,but this time Android gives me error code of -13000,no idea what that means.Please let me know if you found out any solution

Comment: When i do ref.writeToFile(file), it gives me same error, on Android